# How to display the menu items on the Top of Hyperlink

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a hyperlink .On putting the Mouse over it Iam displaying the menu in the bottom . I want to display the Menu over the top.The menu at the bottom is displaying fine. I have to display on top.How can ichange the style in such way i display on top.

**CSS:**

```
.menudiv{
    position:absolute;  
    top: -10px; 
    border: 1px solid #BBB; 
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    font:normal 11px Verdana;
    line-height:10px;
    z-index:100;
    background-color: white;
    width: 75px;
    visibility: hidden; 
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id= "menu3" class="menudiv">
    <a href ="test.php">test1</a>
    <a href ="test1.php">test2</a>
</div>
<a href ="#" rel ="menu3">menu1</a>
```

This providdes a drop down menu for hyperlink but it is displaying at bottom.Now  i need to display the menu on top for the hyperlink.

Comment: Are you using javascript? Because you'll need it in case you need to display multilevel menus. In any case, I'd recommend you to use nested `ul`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

think your menu height is 40px; so you can set the bottom of `.menudiv` for this; look:

```
.menudiv{
    position:absolute;  
    /* top: -10px; */
    bottom: 40px; /*  here you must set the bottom attribute, instead of top attr */
    border: 1px solid #BBB; 
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    font:normal 11px Verdana;
    line-height:10px;
    z-index:100;
    background-color: white;
    width: 75px;
    visibility: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: better yet. `bottom:100%` and make the menu `position:relative`

Comment: Javad:it is displaying the menu on the top but .when i hover over the hyperlink the menu is coming on top with the menu  being expanded horizontally and making the hyperlink(menu1) disappear.how do i fix this

Comment: your example is not helpful, hmmm, you must set a tags, display:block, and position:relative; but this is just an idea. if you can post your complete code here, is better to understand your code and help you

Comment: checkout this: http://jsfiddle.net/Javad_Amiry/pagun/ for a sample. however there, jsfiddle excludes links from spans and the code does not work, but you can copy (and paste) the code in a html file and test it.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Ok so I assume you have this menu in a container that is `position:relative`. If that's the case and you want to display the menu upward you need to specify the bottom attribute as 100%.</strike> or not

You need to make a container for this as well

http://jsfiddle.net/wbVLF/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menuContainer">
    <div id= "menu3" class="menudiv">
        <a href ="test.php">test1</a>
        <a href ="test1.php">test2</a>
    </div>
    <a href ="#" rel ="menu3">menu1</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menudiv{
    position:absolute;  
    top: -10px; 
    border: 1px solid #BBB; 
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    font:normal 11px Verdana;
    line-height:10px;
    z-index:100;
    background-color: white;
    width: 75px;
}

.menuContainer{position:relative;}
```